# app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}"); not working in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I put it in the Startup.cs's Configure method

```
        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
```

Then I created a controller like this:

```
[Route("Error/{statusCode}")]
    public IActionResult HandleErrorCode(int statusCode)
    {
        var statusCodeData = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

        switch (statusCode)
        {
            case 404:
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry the page you requested could not be found";
                ViewBag.RouteOfException = statusCodeData.OriginalPath;
                break;
            case 500:
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry something went wrong on the server";
                ViewBag.RouteOfException = statusCodeData.OriginalPath;
                break;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

When I navigate to localhost:port/doesnt-exist

Sigh ... I get a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the blank page was that the View was not being found. Because I am no longer using developer exception pages I couldn't realize it easily.

```
 I used 

 View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml")
```

instead of

```
  View();
```